# Trying to add share button for blog articles

Tags: blog, social-media, social-sharing-buttons

I have added share buttons to the articles on this page:

```
http://185.37.226.104/noticias
```

I have used the code generated [here](https://www.addthis.com/get/sharing). As you can see there are multiple articles on the same page, I have done it like that because the articles will be not too long. So I have to use [this structure](http://support.addthis.com/customer/portal/questions/5024966-multiple-share-button-on-same-page).

The problem: when I press "Like" on one article, nothing happens, any help?

Comment: It's coded incorrectly, you need to be using the URL of each article in the `foreach` loop so that each set of sharing widgets shares the appropriate URL (currently, 1 share on FB will replicate across all instances on the same page).

Answer (score 1):

[zigojacko](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/users/12183/zigojacko) says in a comment:

It's coded incorrectly, you need to be using the URL of each article in the foreach loop so that each set of sharing widgets shares the appropriate URL (currently, 1 share on FB will replicate across all instances on the same page).